# Can you guess me?

Tags: riddle, wordplay

Who am I?

> Your sixth Finger
>
> I run faster, You run slower
>
> My biggest enemy is my doppelganger
>
> Choo Choo(Resemblance)
>
> I don't weigh much
>
> Touch me and I will hurt you back

More hints will be added if it is hard, I don't think it's hard though.

P.S The last clue was because i think it give you a vast opportunities without the last clue , so trying to make the circle smaller.

Comment: Finger and You have capital letters on purpose?

Comment: Sounds like a shadow

Comment: @stackreader No. It was just meant as an exaggeration.

Comment: @somebody That doesnt match with the questions, except the last part though :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess you may be a

> Cigarette

Your sixth Finger

> Held in the hand between fingers.

I run faster, You run slower

> If you smoke fast you'll find running difficult.

My biggest enemy is my doppelganger

> Maybe look-alike electronic versions will put you out of business.

Choo Choo (Resemblance)

> Both go puff puff.

I don't weigh much

> They are light. Weigh less than a pipe.

Touch me and I will hurt you back

> A lit one can burn you if touching the tip. Also just smoking is harmful.

Comment: Wow, that's really clever. If this isn't the answer, it should be.

Comment: Nice. I like the riddle now :) +1 (I hope this should be the intended answer)

Comment: OMG, I was never happy to find that someone got the answer. Finally someone got the answer , Kudos. +1 you are Awesome Tom.

Comment: Thanks to you @Jeffin for your creative, well-clued  and smokily obscured puzzle!

Comment: Haha , thanks for the appreciation , this kind of appreciation will make me make more puzzles , But i still dont know why it was downvoted by a few people though.

Comment: This was surely up to snuff, maybe some response was due to anti-tobacco but you did a warning label at the end. Please do make more - I find it tough and think yours are original.

Comment: Could also make the title related to the solution. Look forward to any you can create!

Comment: @Jeffin I suspect the downvotes came when the puzzle was just the first three clues - without the latter three, the riddle did not have enough in it to point toward a single answer.  With the riddle expanded to the six clues now provided it is (now) well clued and effectively points a solver toward a single solution, but without those clues at first the downvotes would be understandable (and probably warranted).  Thanks for expanding it, and hopefully taking some guidance away from this experience to improve your next puzzle!

Comment: @Rubio - haha , no , the downvotes started when all the clues were present and people still couldn't figure out the solution and am not accepting the correct answer. well, there wasnt one. whatever , am still going to post more of em.

Answer (score 7):

You are

> My nose

Your sixth Finger

> I always use my nose to pick up a phone call, when I'm wearing gloves or my hands are full

I run faster, You run slower

> You have to stop every time you blow your runny nose

My biggest enemy is my doppelganger

> I'm not sure about this one, maybe about it getting in the way when kissing

Choo Choo

> Bless you? In japan this is an onomatopoeia.

Comment: No ,. I dont know how you got 6 +1's though. haha.

Answer (score 6):

After the update to the question, my new answer is a

> Locomotive train.

```
Your sixth Finger
```

> Possible reference to [Tom Thumb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tom_Thumb_%28locomotive%29), an early steam-powered train.

```
I run faster, You run slower
```

> Over long distances, trains move faster than humans or horses.

```
My biggest enemy is my doppelganger
```

> If two trains are on the same track, then they can collide into each other.

```
Choo Choo
```

> The sound of a train whistle.

Comment: Wow ,Unfortunaltely no. I don't know people can get more answers. I should have added one more clue though , awesome effort brother , +1 for that effort

Comment: @Jeffin Provided a new answer to account for the new clue.

Comment: Still not the answer Mike. Its very simple . Ok adding a new clue just for you.

Answer (score 3):

(longshot) Could refer to:

> A thumb?

Your sixth Finger

> Counting your fingers (on one hand and then the other) up to 6 would land you at the thumb unless you don't start with a thumb (or are missing digits) but that's be ridicules.

I run faster, You run slower.

> Just try running with your arms completely still... It's bloody weird.  And when you swing you're arms, your thumbs are moving faster than you.

My biggest enemy is my doppelganger

> 1 2 3 4 I declare a thumb war...?

Comment: haha , I appreciate your effort . But sorry , its not the right answer. awesome effort though.

Answer (score 2):

You are

> Wrist watch

Your sixth finger

> Second's needle

I run faster, You run slower

> Time run's faster.

My biggest enemy is my doppelganger

> Hour and minute needle

Choo Choo

> Sound of needle movement.

Comment: Not quite fitting than the other answers. appreciate your effort though.

Answer (score 2):

You may be

> Mobile phones

```
Your sixth Finger
```

> Most of the time we are holding the mobile phones in hand.

```
I run faster, You run slower
```

> Run - means the RAM running speed. (not sure)

```
My biggest enemy is my doppelganger
```

> Some of the low budget mobile phones were copied their design from the successful model phones.

```
Choo Choo
```

> Not sure about this.

```
I don't weigh much
```

> Mobile phones won't weigh much.

Comment: No Arulkumar , thats not the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are:

> a shadow!

Your sixth Finger

> You can move your fingers + their shadow. A shadow is not useful enough to be called Sixth finger but it's my best guess.

I run faster, You run slower

> You cannot outrun your shadow when the sun is behind you

My biggest enemy is my doppelganger

> You are your shadow's biggest enemy, you have full control of it

Choo Choo

> object(Choo) and its shadow (Choo) look alike. How is Choo Choo a hint I don't get it!?

I don't weigh much

> shadows don't weight at all

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! (Take the **[Tour!](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour)**)  Thank you for your answer and for explaining it!  Note that we generally put Spoiler tags around answers to avoid revealing the answers to someone who wants to try to solve the puzzle on their own.  (You need '>!' for spoilers.)  I've added the spoilers for you.

Comment: @Rubio♦ Thanks! I'll make sure to use it next time :)